# Run java -jar within a new tmux session detached

Tags: java, shell, tmux

I have a problem with tmux.
What I want to achieve is to run a java programm inside a new tmux session.
So lets say I want to start the application 5 times: Then the script should create 5 tmux sessions and run inside of those "java -jar ...".
Afterwards I want the ability to attach to those sessions.

Thats the script which does not work:

```
for i in $(seq 1 "$amount"); do

  tmux new-session -d -s "node$i"
  tmux attach -t "node$i"

   
  tmux send-keys 'java -jar ...' C-m

  counter=$((counter+1))

  tmux detach -t "node$i"
done
```

Hope you can help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: What doesn’t happen?

Comment: It does not open a new tmux terminal with the java program running.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: It opens one attached tmux terminal with the name node01 but no command is executed. If i left the terminal with ctrl + d it opens a new tmux terminal with the name node02 and so on...

Comment: No knowledge about tmux. Would suggest looking into whether “tmux attach” does what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Ive got it running with this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 "$amount"); do

  tmux new-session -d -s "node$i"

  tmux send-keys -t "node$i" "java -jar ... " ENTER

  counter=$((counter+1))

done
```